# How can toolbar transparency be modified?

Tags: interface, customization

Transparent toolbar functionality was released in 2.66, how do I enable transparent toolbars and how can I modify how transparent they are?

Seen here:
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.66/Usability

I would like mine to resemble the toolbars shown in the screenshot, very low opacity.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Enable *Region Overlap* in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>*→ User Preferences → System*:

[image]

To modify the transparency of the sidebars, change the *Alpha* value of *User Preferences → Themes → 3D view → Region background*:

[image] [image]